# Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, crud

controller

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("staffmodel","staff");
}

function index()
{
    $data['staff'] = $this->staff->getAll();
    $this->load->view("staff/index",$data);
}

function create()
{
    if(@$_POST['create_staff'])
    {
        $data = $this->input->post('staff');
        $this->staff->add($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message',"staff created successfully");
        redirect("staff");
    }
    $this->load->view("staff/create");
}

function edit()
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $post = $this->staff->getById($id);
    if(!$post)
    {
        redirect("staff");
    }

    if(@$_POST['update_staff'])
    {
        $postdata = $_POST['staff'];
        $this->staff->update($postdata,$id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message',"Staff updated successfully");
        redirect("staff");
    }

    $data['staff'] = $post;
    $this->load->view("staff/edit",$data);
}

function delete()
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->staff->delete($id);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message',"Staff deleted successfully");
    redirect("staff");
}
```

Model

```
var $table = "staff";
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function getAll()
{
    $q = $this->db->get($this->table);
    if($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    return array();
}

function add($data)
{
    $this->db->insert($this->table,$data);
}

function update($data,$id)
{
    $this->db->where("id",$id);
    $this->db->update($this->table,$data);
}

function delete($id)
{
    $this->db->where("id",$id);
    $this->db->delete($this->table);
}

function getById($id)
{
    $this->db->where("id",$id);
    $q = $this->db->get($this->table);
    if($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $q->row();
    }
    return false;
}
```

i just can't figure out what this error indicates 
  .................................................................................................
i can't find a way to solve this error please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
$postdata = $_POST['staff'];
```

to this

```
$postdata = $_POST;
```

It may work. Since you are directly posting `staff` array to that variable, by default it is taking `0` as key.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax Error: Remove `var` in the first line

```
$table = "staff";
```